# Django, pip packages

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to install packages through  pip and I have this error. I do not know what it is. Where my problem? Tell me please.

```
*** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    [thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/utils.
    core/master_utils.o is up to date
    core/emperor.o is up to date
    core/notify.o is up to date
    [thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/mule.o
    [thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/subscription.o
    [thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/stats.o
    [thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/sendfile.o
    [thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/async.o
    [thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_checks.o
    [thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/fifo.o
    [thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/offload.o
    In file included from /usr/include/fcntl.h:289:0,
                     from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/file.h:24,
                     from ./uwsgi.h:267,
                     from core/utils.c:1:
    In function ‘open’,
        inlined from ‘uwsgi_tmpfd’ at core/utils.c:3517:5:
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:50:4: error: call to ‘__open_missing_mode’ declared with attribute error: open with O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE in second argument needs 3 arguments
        __open_missing_mode ();
        ^
    [thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/io.o
    [thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/static.o

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of uWSGI
Command "/home/maic/secl/en/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PL4ctC/uWSGI/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-JIHVnz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/maic/secl/en/include/site/python2.7/uWSGI" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PL4ctC/uWSGI/
```

Comment: solution: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/f55604ba3d916ab39354af67852583ec79038710 I just googled

Comment: Where this file? stack_trace.ccp? my OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Try cleaning out your `/tmp/` files and re `pip install`